# how to Avoid self-join in spark scala

Tags: sql, dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame called **product_relationship_current** and I'm doing a self-join to retrieve a new DataFrame like bellow:

First I'm giving it an alias so I could consider them like two different dataframes:

```
val pr1 = product_relationship_current.alias("pr1").where(col("TYPE").isin("contains", "CONTAINS"))
val pr2 = product_relationship_current.alias("pr2")
```

And then I'm doing a self-join to get a new dataframe:

```
val stackoutput = pr1.join(pr2, pr1("PRODUCT_VERSION_ID_RELATED_FK") === pr2("PRODUCT_VERSION_ID_FK"), "left")
  .select(pr1("PRODUCT_ID"), pr1("PRODUCT_VERSION"), pr1("RELATED_PRODUCT_ID"), pr1("RELATED_PRODUCT_VERSION"), pr1("TYPE"), pr1("PRODUCT_VERSION_ID_RELATED_FK"))
  .distinct()
```

But I'm looking for another way to do that without doing a self-join, so I don't have to load the same dataframe twice because it is taking so long to be executed. (my **product_relationship_current** dataframe is too large).

This is the SQL query I tried to perform using spark scala:

```
select 
  distinct pr1.product_id as IO, 
  pr1.product_version as IOV, 
  pr1.related_product_id, 
  pr1.related_product_version, 
  pr1.type, 
  pr1.product_version_id_related_fk 
from 
  product_relationship_current as pr1 
  left join product_relationship_current as pr2 on pr1.product_version_id_related_fk = pr2.product_version_id_fk 
where 
  pr1.type = 'contains'
```

Comment: "But I'm looking for another way to do that without doing a self-join, so I don't have to load the same dataframe twice because it is taking so long to be executed" why don' t you persist the df then?

Comment: which storage level should I specify in persist() ? Disk only ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll structure this answer in 2 parts: my answer, and a question.

**My answer**

If you want to avoid to read a dataframe twice, you can use `df.cache` to cache it into memory/disk. `df.cache` is basically `df.persist` using the default [storage level](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/storage/StorageLevel$.html#MEMORY_AND_DISK:org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel) (MEMORY_AND_DISK).

I made a makeshift CSV file (data.csv) with your columns in there. Then I wrote something like this:

```
val df = spark.read.option("delimiter", ";").option("header", "true").csv("data.csv").cache
val df1 = df.filter(df("TYPE").isin("contains", "CONTAINS"))
val output = df1.alias("df1")
  .join(df.alias("df"), col("df1.PRODUCT_VERSION_ID_RELATED_FK") === col("df.PRODUCT_VERSION_ID_FK"), "left")
  .select(df1("PRODUCT_ID"), df1("PRODUCT_VERSION"), df1("RELATED_PRODUCT_ID"), df1("RELATED_PRODUCT_VERSION"), df1("TYPE"), df1("PRODUCT_VERSION_ID_RELATED_FK"))
  .distinct()
```

So you see that I used the `.cache` method on the first line. Now, how can we verify that this worked? I had a look at the Spark UI (runs on port 4040 by default wherever your driver process is running. In my case, I ran `spark-shell` locally so I could access the UI on `localhost:4040`)

By looking at the query plan or visualisation of it we can understand what the effect of `.cache` is. I ran the code above twice: once where I did not `.cache` my dataframe and one where I did.

The first image that I'll drop here is one where I did not `.cache` my dataframe.

[image: Dataframe was not cached]

The second image is one where I did `.cache` my dataframe.

[image: Dataframe was cached]

So you see the difference at the top of the images: because the dataframe was cached the CSV file (or whatever source you are using) won't be read in twice: you see that we have a `InMemoryTableScan` block in both branches instead of a `Scan csv` block.

**Important**: If your data is so large that it does not fit into the combined memory of your executors, the data will spill over to disk. This will make this operation slower.

**My question to you**: It seems like you're doing a left join with `pr1` being the left table, and afterwards you're only selecting columns from the pr1 part of the table. Is this join even needed? Seems like you could just select the wanted columns and then `.distinct` the dataframe.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer..yes it's true I was doing a mistake in my select by selecting only the left side

Comment: Oh ok, happy the answer helped :) Have a good one!